# IndexError: list index out of range Python inputMat

Tags: python, numpy

```
C:\Python34>python first.py q2data.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 13, in <module>
    inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone explain this error, I've been getting errors recently in Python and much of the info I read on it rectifies it but doesn't explain what is happenning, the program is:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

header = txt.readline().split()
inputArray = map(float, txt.readline().split())
txt.close()

inputMat = np.mat(inputArray)
inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
inputMat.shape()

#takes q2data as input
def first(A):
    #Decomposes a nxn matrix A by PA=LU and returns L, U and P.
    n = len(A)
    L = [[0.0] * n for i in xrange(n)]
    U = [[0.0] * n for i in xrange(n)]

    #Creates the pivoting matrix for m.
    n = len(A)
    ID = [[float(i == j) for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
    for j in xrange(n):
        row = max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(A[i][j]))
        if j != row:
            ID[j], ID[row] = ID[row], ID[j]
    p = ID

    #perform matrix multplication
    TA = zip(*A)
    A2 = [[sum(eP*ea for eP,ea in zip(P,a)) for a in TA] for P in p]

    for j in xrange(n):
        L[j, j] = 1.0
        for i in xrange(j+1):
            s1 = sum(U[k, j] * L[i, k] for k in xrange(i))
            U[i, j] = A2[i, j] - s1
        for i in xrange(j, n):
            s2 = sum(U[k, j] * L[i, k] for k in xrange(j))
            L[i, j] = (A2[i, j] - s2) / U[j, j]
    return (L, U, p)

print (first(inputMat))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is simply described in your error message:

```
File "first.py", line 13, in <module>
    inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It says in line 13, you are referring to an element whose index is out of the index range of your list, example:

```
myList = [1,2,3]
print myList[0]
print myList[1]
print myList[2]
print myList[3]# This will throw an IndexError exception like yours,
```

So, you need to make sure that header list has at least two elements when you do :

```
header = txt.readline().split()
```

Definitely there are lines or probably first line on your `filename`  file has less than two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your exception thrown on this line:

```
inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
```

You need to ensure that the list `header` is actually a length of 2 before you use it. What's happening is that your input text file `filename` has its first line containing less than 2 words when you do your `split()`.

Comment: Thanks, my text file was messed up, but I'm getting a different error this time: C:\Python34>python first.py q2data.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 13, in <module>
    inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: The info for that is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html You cannot change the shape of an array if it means changing the total number of elements. For example if the shape of your array is (2,4) (2x4 = 8 elements), then you can only change it's shape to (8, 1), since that will also have 8 elements.